# Sub Array / List is null in JQUERY 1.4.2 AJAX post, using Struts 2.3.34 and struts json pluin 2.3.34

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, struts2

I am using  jQuery 1.4.2, Struts 2.3.34, and Struts JSON plugin 2.3.34.

While posting values from webpage to Action, things are fine at the beginning. But if I added a sub-array/list to the bean, the sub-array/list becomes `null` after posting.

Please see bean definition and action mapping in `struts.xml` below.

**BasicBean**

```
public class BasicBean implements Serializable {
  private String partNumber;
  private List<SubBean> subBeanList;

  public List<SubBean> getSubBeanList() {
    return subBeanList;
  }
  public void setSubBeanList(List<SubBean> subBeanList) {
    this.subBeanList = subBeanList;
  }
  public String getPartNumber() {
    return partNumber;
  }
  public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
    this.partNumber = partNumber;
  }
}
```

**SubBean.java**

```
public class SubBean implements Serializable {
  private String maxCritical;
  private String minCritical;

  public String getMaxCritical() {
    return maxCritical;
  }
  public void setMaxCritical(String maxCritical) {
    this.maxCritical = maxCritical;
  }
  public String getMinCritical() {
    return minCritical;
  }
  public void setMinCritical(String minCritical) {
    this.minCritical = minCritical;
  }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="jsTest" method="doJSon" class="com.jst.action.JSTest">   
  <result name="error"  type="json">
    <param name="includeProperties">errorResult.*</param>
  </result>
  <result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="root">result</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

**JavaScript of JQuery Ajax**

```
var sbList = [];

localData = {
  '"maxCritical"' : '8',
  '"minCritical"' : '9'     
}

sbList.push(localData);

finalData = {
  'bb.partNumber':'6',
  'bb.subBeanList' : sbList
}

$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: updateUrl,
  data: finalData,
  cache: false,     
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(msg){
  if (msg.errorResult) {
    if(msg.errorResult["error_code"] == "session_expired"){
      sessionExpired();
    }
    return;
  }
    jAlert("OK");           
  }     
});
```

As per debug window, sub bean values were POSTed to server:

[image]

But it's `null` on server side, but other element Partnumber were posted successfully:

[image]

Comment: Did you try using rational property names for the sub-bean's properties? You're quoting the name which would probably blow up OGNL. It may not solve the problem, but it's likely incorrect as posted.

Comment: Hi, Gentleman, thanks for your reply. So you are saying that I should change property names of sub-bean ? if so, what names should I change them to ? Please provide suggestion.

Comment: I'm saying remove the quotes around the name. I don't know if that'll fix the problem, but it's certainly incorrect as shown.

Comment: I removed quotes but it did not work. I saw below warning messages   

Jun 12, 2018 12:13:04 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor warn
WARNING: Parameter [bb.subBeanList[0][maxCritical]] didn't match accepted pattern [[\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\(\d+\))|(\['(\w|[\u4e00-\u9fa5])+'\])|(\('(\w|[\u4e00-\u9fa5])+'\)))*]]!